# SwiftUI: custom Font on MacOS

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swiftui

Goal: use a custom Font on SwiftUI, targeting MacOS.

Problem: On iOS, custom Font works fine in SwiftUI:
[image]

But on MacOS, it doesn't:
[image]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .font(Font.custom("SourceCodePro-ExtraLight", size: 40))
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .font(Font.custom("LobsterTwo", size: 40))

        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Tried: I made sure that both fonts are added to Info tab on corresponding iOS and MacOs targets:
[image]
[image]

Seems to be a problem with SwiftUI using UIFont under the hood, and a special NSFont would be needed...

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

Solved by adding this line to the plist file, and a "." as the value

Comment: I <3 you @mane! I have been fighting this for hours. Everything tells me to update the info.plist file directly (etc etc). No change. This image above was the first to indicate that this value can be changed/added in PROJECT/TARGET/INFO settings! FTW